# Products and data is not displaying on front page in tablet of pc mode only showing in mobile mode

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce website I have header section then I have a slider. Till here everything is fine but after slider I added a text in H2 tag and then I displayed the featured products on front page but issues is these are only showing in mobile mode when I inspect and change the mode to Mobile mode but not showing in Laptop screen. Only header and slider is displaying not else and slider is also not fully displaying lower side of pictures is missing
Here is the code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
<div class="section">
    
    <?php
echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider="2"]');
?>
    </div>
</div>
<h2 class="text-center">
<span class="span-green" style="color: #00c9c9!important;">Featured</span> Products
</h2>
<div class="product-slider-wrapp" style="display: inline-flex;
position: relative;">

<?php
$meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
$tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
$tax_query[] = array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
'field'    => 'name',
'terms'    => 'featured',
'operator' => 'IN',
);

$args = array(
'post_type'           => 'product',
'post_status'         => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'      => 4,
'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {

while ($featured_query->have_posts()) : 
 
    $featured_query->the_post();
     
    $product = wc_get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );
    $price = $product->get_price_html();
     
?>
<div class="featured-product">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
</a>
<?php echo $price; ?>
</div>
<?php
     
     
endwhile;
 
}
?>
</div>





<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you inspect the elements with the browser's dev tool ? Since you're using woocomerce it comes with its own css, there might be a media query in there that's causing the issue. Also check your css.

Comment: @Xanthous I inspect with browser dev tool and I tried my best to figure out what's missing here but could not find my error also I have done little bit inline css till now. I think I have done something wrong with bootstrap classses but I cannot figure it out

Comment: Is your element still in the DOM when you can't see it ? Does it have `display : none`, try to see if it's not hidden by another element

Comment: @Xanthous find the solution actually in body class overflow was hidden so I just remove this property and now its working